# I want to enable LTV signature for a digital signature field using PDFTron SDK

Tags: c++, pdf, digital-signature, pdftron

I'm trying to achieve an LTV signature using PDFTron, but I don't know how to add DSS information.
I'm using this sample code, but I don't know how to enable LTV for my signature.
In their sample, they are enabling LTV for the Document Timestamp Signature field, not for the initial signature field

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/cpp/DigitalSignaturesTest

[My signature looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbGDx.png)

But

[I want my signature to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYpH5.png)

I'm using a custom signature handler (OpenSSLSignature Handler)

Comment: What exact DSS info are you looking to add? What is the exact PDFTron code you tried?

Comment: https://github.com/adelinvoicu/Licenta

Comment: This is my code

Comment: https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.01_60/ts_10277804v010101p.pdf

Comment: I try to enable LTV for this signature

Comment: In the "DigitalSignaturesTest" sample you linked to did you see the function TimestampAndEnableLTV? The logic from that function is missing from your github code.

Answer (score -1):

**Use below JavaScript code**

```
const TimestampAndEnableLTV = async (in_docpath, in_trusted_cert_path, in_appearance_img_path, in_outpath) => {
      const doc = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.createFromURL(in_docpath);
      doc.initSecurityHandler();
      doc.lock();
      const doctimestamp_signature_field = await doc.createDigitalSignatureField();
      const tst_config = await PDFNet.TimestampingConfiguration.createFromURL('http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced');
      const opts = await PDFNet.VerificationOptions.create(PDFNet.VerificationOptions.SecurityLevel.e_compatibility_and_archiving);
      /* It is necessary to add to the VerificationOptions a trusted root certificate corresponding to the chain used by the timestamp authority to sign the timestamp token, in order for the timestamp response to be verifiable during DocTimeStamp signing. It is also necessary in the context of this function to do this for the later LTV section, because one needs to be able to verify the DocTimeStamp in order to enable LTV for it, and we re-use the VerificationOptions opts object in that part. */
      await opts.addTrustedCertificateFromURL(in_trusted_cert_path);
      /* By default, we only check online for revocation of certificates using the newer and lighter OCSP protocol as opposed to CRL, due to lower resource usage and greater reliability. However, it may be necessary to enable online CRL revocation checking in order to verify some timestamps (i.e. those that do not have an OCSP responder URL for all non-trusted certificates). */
      await opts.enableOnlineCRLRevocationChecking(true);

      const widgetAnnot = await PDFNet.SignatureWidget.createWithDigitalSignatureField(doc, new PDFNet.Rect(0, 100, 200, 150), doctimestamp_signature_field);
      await (await doc.getPage(1)).annotPushBack(widgetAnnot);

      // (OPTIONAL) Add an appearance to the signature field.
      const img = await PDFNet.Image.createFromURL(doc, in_appearance_img_path);
      await widgetAnnot.createSignatureAppearance(img);

      console.log('Testing timestamping configuration.');
      const config_result = await tst_config.testConfiguration(opts);
      if (await config_result.getStatus()) {
        console.log('Success: timestamping configuration usable. Attempting to timestamp.');
      } else {
        // Print details of timestamping failure.
        console.log(await config_result.getString());
        if (await config_result.hasResponseVerificationResult()) {
          const tst_result = await config_result.getResponseVerificationResult();
          console.log('CMS digest status: ' + (await tst_result.getCMSDigestStatusAsString()));
          console.log('Message digest status: ' + (await tst_result.getMessageImprintDigestStatusAsString()));
          console.log('Trust status: ' + (await tst_result.getTrustStatusAsString()));
        }
        return false;
      }

      await doctimestamp_signature_field.timestampOnNextSave(tst_config, opts);

      // Save/signing throws if timestamping fails.
      let docbuf = await doc.saveMemoryBuffer(PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_incremental);
      saveBufferAsPDFDoc(docbuf, in_outpath);

      console.log('Timestamping successful. Adding LTV information for DocTimeStamp signature.');

      // Add LTV information for timestamp signature to document.
      const timestamp_verification_result = await doctimestamp_signature_field.verify(opts);
      if (!(await doctimestamp_signature_field.enableLTVOfflineVerification(timestamp_verification_result))) {
        console.log('Could not enable LTV for DocTimeStamp.');
        return false;
      }
      docbuf = await doc.saveMemoryBuffer(PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_incremental);
      saveBufferAsPDFDoc(docbuf, in_outpath);
      console.log('Added LTV information for DocTimeStamp signature successfully.');

      return true;
    };
```

Comment: Are you sure your example is written in C++ as desired by the OP?

Comment: that is JavaScript code.

Comment: Well, the question was about C++...

Comment: @mkl could you please try to use next answer which is in c++. I am 100% sure that it's worked.

Comment: *"could you please try to use next answer which is in c++. I am 100% sure that it's worked."* - Well, that's for @3de to try, it's their question after all. I merely stumbled over your original answer and was pretty sure that C++ could not have changed that much...

Answer (score -1):

**Please try to use below c++ code.**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <openssl/applink.c>

#include “OpenSSLSignatureHandler.h”

void SignPDF(const UString& in_docpath, const UString& in_approval_field_name, const UString& in_private_key_file_path, const UString& in_keyfile_password, const UString& in_appearance_img_path, const UString& in_outpath) { /*

During the certification of a document, you are still using a digital signature to guarantee the integrity of the document. However, you are also adding additional restriction on the document preventing further action on it.

The certification of a document being a reliable option, no futher action is possible once this has been applied:       :the modification will then need to be done on the original « non-sign/certified » document.

The option to certify is only available to the first signer of the document.

*/

cout << "================================================================================" << endl; cout << "Signing PDF document" << endl;

// Open an existing PDF PDFDoc doc(in_docpath);

// Retrieve the unsigned approval signature field. Field found_approval_field(doc.GetField(in_approval_field_name)); PDF::DigitalSignatureField found_approval_signature_digsig_field(found_approval_field);

// Add an appearance to the signature field. PDF::Image img = PDF::Image::Create(doc, in_appearance_img_path); Annots::SignatureWidget found_approval_signature_widget(found_approval_field.GetSDFObj()); found_approval_signature_widget.CreateSignatureAppearance(img);

// Prepare the signature and signature handler for signing. OpenSSLSignatureHandler sigHandler(in_private_key_file_path.ConvertToUtf8().c_str(), in_keyfile_password.ConvertToUtf8().c_str()); SignatureHandlerId sigHandlerId = doc.AddSignatureHandler(sigHandler); found_approval_signature_digsig_field.SignOnNextSaveWithCustomHandler(sigHandlerId);

/* Add to the digital signature dictionary a SubFilter name that uniquely identifies the signature format for verification tools. As an example, the custom handler defined in this file uses the CMS/PKCS #7 detached format, so we embed one of the standard predefined SubFilter values: "adbe.pkcs7.detached". It is not necessary to do this when using the StdSignatureHandler. */ Obj f_obj = found_approval_signature_digsig_field.GetSDFObj(); f_obj.FindObj("V").PutName("SubFilter", "adbe.pkcs7.detached");

// The actual approval signing will be done during the following incremental save operation. doc.Save(in_outpath, SDFDoc::e_incremental, NULL);

cout << "================================================================================" << endl; }

void addDTSandEnableLTV(const UString& in_docpath,const UString& in_approval_field_name,const UString& tsa_cer_path,const UString& in_outpath) { PDFDoc doc(in_docpath);

Field found_approval_field(doc.GetField(in_approval_field_name)); PDF::DigitalSignatureField found_approval_signature_digsig_field(found_approval_field);

TimestampingConfiguration tst_config("https://freetsa.org/tsr"); VerificationOptions opts(VerificationOptions::e_compatibility_and_archiving); opts.AddTrustedCertificate("./Certificate V2/cacert.pem"); opts.EnableOnlineCRLRevocationChecking(true);

puts("Testing timestamping configuration.");

const TimestampingResult config_result(found_approval_signature_digsig_field.GenerateContentsWithEmbeddedTimestamp(tst_config, opts));

if (config_result.GetStatus()){     puts("Success: timestamping configuration usable. Attempting to timestamp."); } else{   // Print details of timestamping failure.   puts(config_result.GetString().ConvertToUtf8().c_str());    if (config_result.HasResponseVerificationResult()){         EmbeddedTimestampVerificationResult tst_result(config_result.GetResponseVerificationResult());      printf("CMS digest status: %s\n", tst_result.GetCMSDigestStatusAsString().ConvertToUtf8().c_str());         printf("Message digest status: %s\n", tst_result.GetMessageImprintDigestStatusAsString().ConvertToUtf8().c_str());      printf("Trust status: %s\n", tst_result.GetTrustStatusAsString().ConvertToUtf8().c_str());  } } }

int main(int * argc ,char * argv[]) { PDFNet::Initialize(“demo:1633957651957:78a80cae03000000006daebb38099f54ad99b64ef524fca4902e1636bd”);

PDFDoc doc("testClear.pdf"); DigitalSignatureField approval_signature_field = doc.CreateDigitalSignatureField("PDFTronApprovalSig");

Annots::SignatureWidget widgetAnnotApproval = Annots::SignatureWidget::Create(doc, Rect(300, 287, 376, 306), approval_signature_field); Page page1 = doc.GetPage(1); page1.AnnotPushBack(widgetAnnotApproval); doc.Save("waiver_withApprovalField_output.pdf", SDFDoc::e_remove_unused, 0);

SignPDF("waiver_withApprovalField_output.pdf", "PDFTronApprovalSig", "./Certificate V2/GemBoxRSA4096.pfx", "GemBoxPassword", "signature.jpg", "signed.pdf");

}
```